# Program not working in my lower version mobile

Tags: blackberry, geolocation

I wrote a code to get the location coordinates using cellsite based location and here is the code i used:

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.setHorizontalAccuracy(Criteria.NO_REQUIREMENT);
criteria.setVerticalAccuracy(Criteria.NO_REQUIREMENT);
criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
criteria.setPreferredPowerConsumption(Criteria.POWER_USAGE_LOW);
try {
    LocationProvider lp=LocationProvider.getInstance(criteria);
    if(lp !=null)
    {
          Location loc=null;
          loc=lp.getLocation(-1);
          if(loc!=null)
               add(new EditField(loc.getQualifiedCoordinates().getLatitude()+"\n"+loc.getQualifiedCoordinates().getLongitude(),""));
          else 
               add(new EditField("no location found",""));
    }
    else
    {
            add(new EditField("unable to find the location provider", ""));
    }
} catch (LocationException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I used Blackberry 8520 mobile with airtel sim card with version 5.0 and it worked perfectly. I got the coordinates and it is fine. Now i used the same application with same sim card with Blackberry 8520 version 4.6.1. When i start the application, it is starting but it is not displaying even the main screen. This is the output when i run the app in 5.0 mobile:[image]

and when i run this in 4.6 i didn't get any screen atleast showing error message. Please provide a solution. Thank you. To clarify further i installed google maps on 4.6 mobile with the same sim card and it showed me the correct location and also there is also no problem in accessing the internet

Comment: Since "it is starting but it is not displaying even the main screen" it looks like some other part of the application (not the code you posted that deals with LocationProvider) has an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Did you compile the app against a version 5 compiler? If yes then your app wont start in os4.6  device. You have to compile in atleast 4.6 jde compiler to get your app working.

Comment: I didn't get you. Can u explain me briefly

Comment: Rihan told that when ever you build your application on particular jar like Blackberry JRE 5.0,it should not work on  Blackberry JRE 4.7(means lower version)

Comment: To put it simply if your app has to work on your 8520 running 4.6.1 , download and install Blackberry JDE 4.5 or 4.6 and then compile in it, then copy the file to the device. It will work.

Comment: you compiled your app and copied it to 4.6.1 device and it doesnt start. I suspect its throwing an exception. How about you try to debug using the device.?

Comment: and also please refer this article. In this it is specified that cell site location in not supported in 4.5, 4.6, 4.7 etc.. [link] http://helpblog.blackberry.com/2010/12/facebook-places-unavailable-location/

Comment: In the debugger also i can't any exception. Everything it is showing as everything is going fine. Did you see the article?

Comment: try to put breakpoints in Application start and see whats happening